# How do I insert a NULL long value?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database made up a single table with several fields, one of which is a phone number that is stored as a NUMERIC. Because the phone number is 10 digits, in my code I have captured the variable as a LONG.

My question is, in the insert statement, how do I pass a NULL value? Is this possible at all? I can't assign a null value to the LONG variable, so I'm wondering how to go about doing this...

Comment: `Long` can take `null`, but `long` cannot.

Comment: Using a numeric field for a phone number has always struck me as odd.

Comment: If you want to insert a value to a LONG field that is easily recognizable as blank or incorrect use 0. You can check against that if you need. But as Eng.Fouad said you can't assign null to a primitive type (`long`) but you can to an object (`Long`).

Comment: Passing Long value with null to the database results in the program crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you desperately need to use numerics for the phone number, why not just code a non-existing phone number into something like 0L or -1L?

*Edit:* Btw, you say that the database is limited to numeric format. Does the same go for the java side?

```
long dbPhoneNumber = getTheLongFieldFromTheDatabase();
String internalPhoneNumberRepresentation = Long.toString(dbPhoneNumber);
doSomethingWithString();
dbPhoneNumber = internalPhoneNumberRepresentation == null ? 0L : internalPhoneNumberRepresentation;
storeLongFieldToDatabase(dbPhoneNumber);
```

Should more or less do all you need, right?

Answer (score 7):

> Because the phone number is 10 digits, in my code I have captured the variable as a LONG.

Bad idea. Phone numbers might *look* like numbers, but they're not. They're strings of characters that happen to be *mostly* digits. But they can also contain symbols such as `+`.

Use a `String` instead.

---

Update: If you are required to use a numeric type then make sure you use `Long` instead of `long`. The capitilazation is important. And by the way, there is no such type as `LONG` in standard Java.

Comment: Yes, or simply start with a 0 (that's the case of *all* the phone numbers where I live)

Comment: I can't use string. The software specifications require the database value be numeric.

Comment: Phone numbers can also be up to 15 digits, not 10 (when dealing with international numbers, which is also where `+` comes into play).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you store a phone number as a numeric field? In most cases you probably also want to store things like "+41 (52) 123 455", which you loose with numeric datatypes, but ok.

Then for inserting null values: What about:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (phone) VALUES (NULL);
```